# finding the max of a series of variables in a data-frame

Tags: r

I have the following data-frame :

```
      id cluster       username 2001 2002 2003 2004 2005 2006 2007  2008  2009  2010   2011
1 268672  Type 1          Vlaam    0    0    0    0    0    0 5896 18976 13552 20508 106939
2 351003  Type 2 WikiCleanerBot    0    0    0    0    0    0    0 17049  8468 22834   7470
   2012  2013  2014  2015  2016
1 83874 97447 59677 88661 41133
2 11219 83245 28015 40464 25053
```

I need to create a last variable, telling me what variable in the 2001, 2002... 2016 series contains, for each row, the **max** of the serie. I write this code :

```
cluster$yearMod <- apply(cluster,1,function(x) {
  years <- x[4:19]
  as.numeric(names(years)[match(max(years),years)])
})
```

But this gave me :

```
[1] 2015 2015
```

Which is absolutely not the correct value, which was 2011 and 2013.

Can you help me ?

Comment: If you need the Mode, use `table`

Comment: sorry my question was not correctly formulated, I needed the max, but not the mode. Can you please remoe the duplicated flag ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is the `max` elements, then we can use `max.col`.  Create a logical index of the numeric column names using `grepl` ('i1'), then subset the dataset based 'i1' (`df1[i1]`) get the index of the `max` value for each row with `max.col` and use that to get the corresponding column names.

```
i1 <- grepl("[0-9]+$", names(df1))
df1$newVar <- names(df1)[i1][max.col(df1[i1], "first")]
df1$newVar
#[1] "2011" "2013"
```

---

If we are using the `apply`, then another option is `which.max`

```
names(df1)[i1][apply(df1[i1], 1, which.max)]
#[1] "2011" "2013"
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(id = c(268672L, 351003L), cluster = c("Type 1", 
"Type 2"), username = c("Vlaam", "WikiCleanerBot"), `2001` = c(0L, 
0L), `2002` = c(0L, 0L), `2003` = c(0L, 0L), `2004` = c(0L, 0L
), `2005` = c(0L, 0L), `2006` = c(0L, 0L), `2007` = c(5896L, 
0L), `2008` = c(18976L, 17049L), `2009` = c(13552L, 8468L), 
`2010` = c(20508L, 
22834L), `2011` = c(106939L, 7470L), `2012` = c(83874L, 11219L
), `2013` = c(97447L, 83245L), `2014` = c(59677L, 28015L), 
`2015` = c(88661L, 
40464L), `2016` = c(41133L, 25053L)), .Names = c("id", "cluster", 
 "username", "2001", "2002", "2003", "2004", "2005", "2006", "2007", 
 "2008", "2009", "2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", "2014", "2015", 
 "2016"), row.names = c("1", "2"), class = "data.frame")
```